# Unable to set GridLayout to a Composite container

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am unable to set a GridLayout to a Composite Container in a Plugin project in Eclipse Neon 3.

The code I am writing for setting the layout to the container is:

```
private Composite container;

@Override
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
    container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1,2);
    container.setLayout(layout);
}
```

The **setLayout()** method is throwing an error stating the following:

> The method setLayout(Layout) in the type Composite is not applicable for the arguments (GridLayout)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing the wrong `GridLayout` class.

You need `org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout`. Only layouts which extend `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout` are acceptable to `setLayout`. A normal SWT application will not have any `java.awt.xxx` imports.

Note that the SWT `GridLayout` does not have a constructor with row and column arguments. You just specify the number of columns and the layout works out the number of rows. Something like:

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false); // 2 columns, different widths
container.setLayout(layout);
```

Comment: thanx for pointing this out to me. I never looked at the imports.
Now the program works perfectly.

Thanx.. :)